# if statement (banking - credit / debit)

Tags: php, html, magento

Question: How can I change the target cell row depending on a positive or negative output value?

The below outputs a number value which is either a deduction (eg. -$500.00), or an addition (eg. $500).

```
<td><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_item->getValueChange())?></td>
```

I am wanting to display bank deductions and additions in separate row cell. Currently they are displaying within the same row cell.

Here is a screenshot of what I mean. I have already created the rows where the values will be placed.

[image]

My coding is as follows:

```
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('Date') ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('Action') ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('Particulars') ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('Added') ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('Deducted') ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('Temporary') ?></th>                                
            <th><?php echo $this->__('Credit Balance') ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($_items as $_item): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $_item->getActionDate()?></td>
                <td><?php echo $this->getActionTypeLabel($_item->getActionType())?></td>                    
                <td><?php echo $_item->getComment()?></td> 
                <td> </td>   
                <td> </td>                
                <td><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_item->getValueChange())?></td>                    
                <td><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_item->getValue())?></td>                    
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </tbody>
```

Can someone please help me out, perhaps by modifying my current code so the values are inserted into the correct cell on my website?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be simplest to just do something like; (untested so see as pseudocode)

```
<?php foreach ($_items as $_item): ?>
  <?php $valuechange = Mage::helper('core')->currency($_item->getValueChange()); ?>
  <tr>
```

...and later...

```
  <td><?php if($valuechange>0) echo $valuechange; ?></td>
  <td><?php if($valuechange<0) echo -$valuechange; ?></td>
```

Comment: Hey man, the above doesn't seem seem to be returning any values. I'll continue to have a bit of a play around. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: I think my problem may be that the deduction symbol "-" could be getting inserted separately...therefore all the values may be positive until this sign is inserted...I'll have to figure out at what stage this sign is inserted and correct.